# suEXEC is enabled but apache is still using "apache" user for every website

Tags: apache-2.2, suexec

I'm using Plesk 12 with some modules enabled, including suexec:

[image: Plesk - Enabled modules]

But when I run `whoami` from a PHP script, I still get apache's default user: `apache`

What am I doing wrong? Should I double check some config file or activate something else?

Comment: Loading the module is not the same as configuring Apache correctly and enabling it for specific sites/content. So yes, you'll need to do something else. Most sysadmins will use configuration files rather than control panels, so how to do so in Plesk, No Idea.

Comment: Using suExec: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_suexec.html#suexecusergroup but typically apache runs as an Apache module meaning you'll need [something else](http://php-fpm.org/)...

Comment: @HBruijin, makes sense. Do you know any good tutorials on that? I'm not very experienced with servers, so any easier instructions would be really nice.

Comment: Administration panels are off topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only way to my knowledge is to have php running with php-fpm pools or as CGI/FastCGI and not as an apache module.

I think plesk allows running php in CGI/FastCGI mode.

Comment: Thanks, man! Got the answer from this post: http://forum.sp.parallels.com/threads/parallels-plesk-file-permission-problem.264947/. It was exactly that, setting PHP to run as FastCGI.